# Can this Assignment and Copy cnstr be organized better

Tags: c++

I am trying to improve my understanding of the copy constructor and copy assign. operator
Here is a simple class that I came up with

```
class Bar
{
    char* name;
    int zip;
    std::string address;

    public:
    Bar(const Bar& that)
    {
            //Copy constructor
            size_t len = strlen(that.name + 1);
            name = new char[len];
            strcpy(name, that.name);

            //Copy the zip
            this->zip = that.zip;

            //Copy the address
            this->address = that.address;
    }
    Bar& operator=(const Bar& that)
    {
        //Assignment operator
        if(this != &that)
        {
            //Copy the name
            size_t len = strlen(that.name + 1);
            name = new char[len];
            strcpy(name, that.name);

            //Copy the zip
            this->zip = that.zip;

            //Copy the address
            this->address = that.address;

        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

My question is since the code in the copy constructor and copy assignment operator are the same does it make more sense to unify that into a deep copy method so that incase I add another member variable I dont have to add another line to the copy cnstr and copy assign. section ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why are you not using `std::String?

Comment: @EdHeal: He is, check again :P

Comment: I am using both. Just in case i run into `char* ` I decided to use that too.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Not for `name`

Comment: I am using char* just for the sake of curiosity

Comment: .. Curiosity kill the cat (and other dodgy 80s bands)

Comment: With the pointer, you have to establish the copy rules:  deep copy or shallow copy.  Also which object owns the target data, as you can have multiple pointers to one object.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: He seems to consistently be doing a deep copy, so that's not an issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" way of doing things where you manage your own resources is a little different:

```
char* cppstrdup(const char*s, int len=0);
class Bar
{
    char* name;
    int zip;
    std::string address;    
public:
    Bar(const Bar& that)
        :name(nullptr),
        zip(that->zip),
        address(that->address)
    {
        name = cppstrdup(that.name); //done here for exception safety reasons
    }
    Bar(Bar&& that) //if you have C++11 then you'll want this too
        :name(nullptr)
    {
        swap(*this,that);
    }
    ~Bar() //you forgot the destructor
    {
        delete [] name;
    }
    Bar& operator=(Bar that) //this is called copy and swap.
    { //"that" is a copy (notice, no & above), and we simply swap
        swap(*this,that);
        return *this;
    }
    friend void swap(Bar& left, Bar& right)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(left.name, right.name);
        swap(left.zip, right.zip);
        swap(left.address, right.address);
    }
};
//uses new instead of malloc
inline char* cppstrdup(const char* s, int len)
{
     if (s==0) return nullptr;
    if (len==0) len = strlen(s);
    char* r = new char[len+1];
    strncpy(r, len+1, s);
    r[len] = 0;
    return r;
}
```

The benefits of this pattern is that it is much easier to get exception safety, often with the strong exception guarantee.

Of course, even more normal is to not use `char*` name, and obey the "Rule of Zero" isntead.  In which case, it becomes VERY different:

```
class Bar
{
    std::string name;
    int zip;
    std::string address;

public:
    Bar() = default; //well, that's easy
};
```

Comment: If you are going to add C++11 to it could you also give out the working of move assignment operator

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Yes, I thought that move constructor was too simple.  Good catch.  `swap` as a friend keeps it out of the global namespace, which keeps error messages simpler, and also gives it access to the private members which it needs to work.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. One last question if `Bar` was derived and had a base class say `BaseBar` How would we handle that in swap method ?

Comment: "The benefits of this pattern is that it is entirely exception safe" ...except for leaking `name` when the copy constructor of `address` throws an exception.

Comment: You've defined a non-member binary swap, but in the assignment operator you call a unary swap

Comment: @MooingDuck could you also answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162091/friend-function-inside-code

Comment: @Casey: Whooops.  Fixed, at least for this case.

Comment: in case of an assignment operator you have to handle the deep copy of the base class yourself.  So if Bar was derived and had a base class say BaseBar How would we handle that in swap method since the assignment operator calls swap ?

Comment: simply add the line `swap((basebar&)(*this), that);` inside of `swap`.  (Since the left is a `basebar&` and the right is a `base`, C++ will select `swap(basebar&,basebar&)`, so we really only need to cast one side manually`).

Comment: `name` needs to be deallocated with `free` instead of `delete[]` - and then I promise to stop nitpicking.

Comment: @Casey: OP was using `new`, so my use of `strdup` was incorrect.  Fixed.  If anything else needs nitpick'd, let me know.  Rather be bothered than have a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check COPY & SWAP idiom. In short - your logic goes into copy constructor and swap method and your assignment operator looks like:

```
Bar& operator=(const Bar& that)
{
    Bar temp(that);
    swap(*this, temp);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Why not have `that` be the copy instead of `temp`?

Comment: What `swap` will that call? I don't think you want the generic `std::swap`