# Friend Function inside code

Tags: c++, friend

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161514/can-this-assignment-and-copy-cnstr-be-organized-better/23161638?noredirect=1#comment35419432_23161638) earlier . The code could be checked from the response.

My question is the author of the post posted this in the move constructor

```
swap(*this,that);
```

and this in the copy assignment operator

```
swap(that);
```

Now I am familiar with the concept of friend functions and have done more reading on it however I am still baffled as to why the second statement only has one parameter whereas the swap method requires two parameters. I would appreciate it if some one can clarify the second statement and why its just passing one parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other of said answer, that was a typo.  Both should have been

```
swap(*this,that);
```

Jonathan Wakely pointed out my error and I have corrected it.

There was no magic involved that you didn't know, hooray!

Comment: The lesson here is that you should compile code before accepting its validity :)